# C++ DLL called from VBA in Excel 2010 only works in administrator mode

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, excel-2010

I have created a simple dll in Visual Studio 2012 that performs a calculation.  I am calling this dll from VBA in Excel 2010 using the following syntax:

```
Declare Sub MyFunction Lib "MyDll.dll" (ByRef param1 As Double, ByVal param2 As Double)
```

This function works perfectly on my development machine.  When I try to run this dll on another computer, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '53': File not found: MyDll.dll
```

However, when I run Excel (on another computer) in administrator (elevated) mode, I don't get this error and everything works perfectly.

Is there any way I can get this to work without having the user run Excel as an administrator?

Comment: maybe the working directory is diffret when in non-admin mode? make ssure the dll is in the working directory

Comment: @GamErix Thanks for your comments.  I'm getting some really weird behavior.  I tried a lot of things, including putting the dll in the System32 directory...but here's what's happening now.  I can run the dll in normal mode (i.e. not as admin) if I specify the *ABSOLUTE* path to the dll as long as it's *NOT* the System32 directory.  For some reason if I give it the *ABSOLUTE* path to the dll in the System32 directory I get the file not found error.  I have to admit that this is really, really strange.

Comment: true, and that just confirms that when you load the dll the application is not looking in the directory where your DLL is, or said in another way: the DLL you specified is not in the current working directory or DLL library directories or PATH variable directories so exel can't find it.

Comment: @GamErix Please kindly put your comments in an answer so I can give you the credit for answering this question.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can guess your DLL is not in the working directory, PATH variable directory or system directory. Excel is not looking in the directory your DLL is so you need to move your DLL into the system directory, one of the PATH variable directories or excels' working directory.